# Typescript Error Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am editing in the database and there was a typescript error 2339
Here is the code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject} from '@ionic-native/sqlite'; 
import { SQLitePorter } from '@ionic-native/sqlite-porter'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the DatabaseProvider provider.

      See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on                     
providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class DatabaseProvider {
    database: SQLiteObject;
    private dbReady: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private sqlitePorter: SQLitePorter,             private storage: Storage, private sqlite: SQLite, private platform: Platform)     
{
    this.dbReady = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.sqlite.create({
            name: 'assessment.db',
            location: 'default'
        })
        .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
            this.database = db;
            this.storage.get('database_filled').then(val => {
                if(val){
                    this.dbReady.next(true);
                }
                else{
                    this.fillDatabase();
                }
            })
        });
    });  
}

fillDatabase(){
    this.http.get('assets/test.sql')
    .map (res => res.text())
    .subscribe(sql => { 
        this.sqlitePorter.importSqlToDb(this.database, sql)
        .then(data => {
            this.dbReady.next(true);
            this.storage.set('database_filled', true);
        })
    });
}

  getDatabaseState(){
    return this.dbReady.asObservable();
  }

}
```

.map (res => res.text()) this part returns an error. I have tried to alter this and made it .map ((res: Response) => res.text()) then another error would prompt and that is in the line this.sqlitePorter.importSqlToDb(this.database, sql) the error is " Argument of type Promise is not assignable to parameter of type .

Answer (score 1):

With `HttpClient`, you no longer need to map the result of a `Http` call as it returns the result by default rather than the response object. If the result of your http call is already a string then just remove the `.map` line. i.e.

```
fillDatabase(){
    this.http.get<string>('assets/test.sql')
    .subscribe(sql => { 
        this.sqlitePorter.importSqlToDb(this.database, sql)
        .then(data => {
            this.dbReady.next(true);
            this.storage.set('database_filled', true);
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: i deleted it the next error is the promise string in this line  this.sqlitePorter.importSqlToDb(this.database, sql) it highlighted sql.

Comment: @RonaCeciliaAbayata, I updated my answer. Your `get` call should specify the return type of the object, which in this case is `string`, otherwise it gets defaulted to be `object`.

Comment: thank you. the first error was solved. now my problem is with this line, this.sqlitePorter.importSqlToDb(this.database, sql) it returns this error (Typescript Error
Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.)

Comment: Did you update your call to be `this.http.get<string>`? If this didn't work, which it should have, update your subscribe line to be `.subscribe((sql: string) => {`

Comment: thank you so much. it did not return an error anymore.